# i need to format my ex HD to FAT32 but i only have exFAT

Tags: external-hard-drive

I had problems with my exHD working on my playstation and was told to change the format settings. I went thru the process of doing this but I found out i dont have FAT32 but exFAT instead. will this still work on the playstation or not? I did change it to exFAT and tried copying movies over but its taking the movie lenght to transfer?!

Comment: Continuation of this discussion....http://superuser.com/questions/177109/wd-passport-elite-not-working-on-playstaion

Answer (score 2):

Windows won't format disks past a certain size (40GB I believe) in FAT32.  However, Linux can do it.  Try downloading and burning the liveCD from [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), boot the disc, and create and format a FAT32 partition there.  Be careful though not to accidentally format your computer's hard drive.

Alternatively, see if you can format it with the Playstation itself.  I am not sure how to do this or if it actually can be done, however.

Comment: True, you'll have to use gparted or one of a few other partitioning tools afaik.

Answer (score 0):

exFat is a proprietary windows file system, so it won't work with play station, you must use Fat32

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=exfat+playstation&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CzynB6CdrTOySNI_KMpSAscYGAAAAqgQFT9AswvY&pbx=1&fp=8631cdd35a4d476d

Comment: He knew that already.

Comment: No they didn't read the question again, I quote " I found out i dont have FAT32 but exFAT instead. will this still work on the playstation or not?"

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct conversion from exFAT to FAT32, even the Convert command won't allow you to convert an exFA volume to NTFS either. The only way is to copy the data off to another volume and reformat to FAT32, and then copy the data back.

Except one additional problem, since Microsoft won't allow you to format any volume larger than 32GB to FAT32, you will have to use a non-Microsoft utility to format your 500GB drive to FAT32.

OR

[Click here](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Add_ExFat_for_Windows_XP_28515994) to see a tutorial. It may helpful for you.

Comment: This does not change the fact that the Playstation doesn't support exFAT.

Comment: Also he wants to reformat since the Playstation does not see exFAT, thus he hasn't saved anything there as of yet.